# When two values, $a$ and $b$, have the same value for their sum, product, and $a^b$...

Tags: real-numbers

### For what values of $a$ and $b$ do the following three expressions assume the same value?
$$a+b,\qquad ab, \qquad a^b$$
and what is that value?

Clearly $\quad (a,b)=(2,2)\quad$ with a corresponding value of $4\quad$is one such answer.

But I stumbled upon another (yet more tricky) *possible* solution:   $$(a,b)\approx  (−3.1410415255\ldots, 0.758514858196\ldots)$$
that also, if you approximate as below, at least seemingly enables the three above expressions to take on the same value:

$\quad\left(\approx −2.3825266673\ldots\right)$.

I'm not sure what to make of this, but I am sure that negative odd rationals raised to an odd power, or an odd rational power, produces a negative number.

Also, somewhat curiously, though the first two are symmetric, the third isn't, yet our values for $a,b$ have $\quad a^b=\pm b^a,\quad$ so that we could say
$$a+b=ab=a^b=\pm b^a$$
For these specific choices of $a$ and $b$.

Any amplifying information about anything regarding this,  **(other than $(-a)^b$ being undefined)**, would be much appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

The overriding conviction here is that $a^b$, as described above, is undefined.  Yet this value,  whatever it's nature,  can be approximated by odd rationals.  Indeed we can all see that $$\boxed{(-\alpha)^\beta<0 \quad \text{if } \quad \alpha, \beta \quad \text{are ratios of odd natural numbers}}$$

*We don't know what these numbers are*,  so why not approximate as below? $$(−3.1410415255\ldots)^{0.758514858196\ldots} \approx \left(-\frac{71}{23}-\frac{1}{19}-\frac{1}{691}\right)^{\left(\frac{17}{23}+\frac{1}{127}+\frac{1}{131}+\frac{1}{283}+\frac{1}{2953}\right)} $$
One can approximate any such number this way to any degree using a suitable arrangement of odd numbers of prime reciprocals.

---

The origin of the question is just my own curiosity/interest...

Comment: How do you compute $(-3.14)^{0.758}\>$?

Comment: Or rather, how do you even _define_ that?

Comment: @IvanNeretin there's ways,  I'm sure you're able to see.

Comment: @TonyK  we don't know exactly what these values ($−3.1410415255\ldots, 0.758514858196\ldots)$ even are.  I know you'll agree that negative odd rationals raised to an odd rational power in the numerator and the denominator would land in the third quadrant.  So why not do this:  $$(−3.1410415255\ldots)^{0.758514858196\ldots} \approx \left(-\frac{71}{23}-\frac{1}{19}-\frac{1}{691}\right)^{\left(\frac{17}{23}+\frac{1}{127}+\frac{1}{131}+\frac{1}{283}\right)}$$

Comment: @TonyK one can always approximate using a sequence of primes, which are always odd (yes other than 2).  This is why I find the argument that it's not defined to be a non-show-stopper.  When you get down to it, you can approximate it as well as you wish using only primes

Comment: Is this what happens when you ask a good question?   You get downvoted, no one answers the question at face value?

Answer (score 1):

The equation has $3$ forms, if you do not choose a shape that satisfies all forms, then you would get limited solutions because of symmetry... I disagree to @YvesDaoust's solution
$$p = a+b = a^b = ab $$
Our trick is to take the equation in two's $ab = a+b$ , $ab = a^b$ , $a+b = a^b$ and solve to see what satisfies each of them then recombine to get a general solution

The symmetric part of the equation is $ab= a+b$ while $a^b$ is non-symmetric, this means we have a fixed choose here, now say that $x \in \{a,b\}$
$$x^2-(a+b)x+ab= 0$$
$$x^2-px+p = 0$$
$$ x = \frac{ p \pm \sqrt{ p^2-4p}}{2}$$
$x$ here is any one of $(a,b)$, so after we find the value of $p$ we can use the quadratic to get both $a$ and $b$
$$a^b = p$$
$$(\frac{ p-\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2})^{(\frac{ p+\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2})} = p$$
This is the equation that satisfies all three, but since we are not specific to which of the $x$ has $a$ or $b$, then we interchange to account for all solutions

$$(\frac{ p+\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2})^{(\frac{ p-\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2})} = p$$

Let's make it finer, by taking $\log()$

$$(\frac{ p-\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2})\cdot \log(\frac{ p+\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2}) = \log(p)$$
You can solve this with newton method to get value of $p$, just becareful of $\log()$

I plotted the function on Wolfram, then I saw some extra solutions, I set to imaginary plot and I saw some complex solutions, you can get the complex solutions also by substituting $p = \alpha + \omega i$, then separating the equation for real and imaginary parts

I saw that another negative $p$ and positive $p$ which lies about $≈6.177$, but because of limited resources I can't put the value here... Remember that if we get $p$, we can extract $a,b$ by solving $x^2-px+p$

$$(\frac{ p-\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2})\cdot \log(\frac{ p+\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2}) = \log(p)$$

$$(\frac{ p+\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2})\cdot \log(\frac{ p-\sqrt{p^2-4p}}{2}) = \log(p)$$

Go ahead and plot the two functions

Comment: I appreciate your unassuming approach to my question.   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The power $a^b$, where $b$ can be any real number is only defined for $a>0$. You may also define it for $a=0$, if you prefer, but in this case the value at $b=0$ cannot be defined by continuity on both variables. You *might* choose to define $0^0=0$, but it would be a stretch.

Anyway, let's assume $a>0$. Then you have
$$
b=\frac{a}{a-1},\qquad b-1=\frac{a-a+1}{a-1}=\frac{1}{a-1}
$$
(clearly, $a\ne1$). From $ab=a^b$ we obtain $b=a^{b-1}$, so
$$
\frac{a}{a-1}=a^{1/(a-1)}
$$
Setting $t=1/a$ we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{1-t}=\frac{1}{t^{t/(1-t)}}
$$
and, in particular, $0<t<1$. Thus we can rewrite the equation as
$$
(1-t)^{1-t}=t^t
$$
or, as well
$$
(1-t)\log(1-t)=t\log t
$$
(natural logarithm). Consider the function
$$
f(t)=t\log t-(1-t)\log(1-t)
$$
Then
\begin{align}
f'(t)&=\log t+1+\log(1-t)+1
\\[6px]
f''(t)&=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{1-t}=\frac{1-2t}{t(1-t)}
\end{align}
Thus $f'$ has a maximum at $1/2$ and
$$
f'(1/2)=2-2\log2>0
$$
Since $\lim_{t\to0}f(t)=\lim_{t\to1}f(t)=-\infty$, we conclude $f'$ vanishes on two points.

Noting that $f(1/4)=\log(16/27)<0$ and using the symmetry around $t=1/2$, we conclude that $f$ has a negative minimum in the interval $(0,1/2)$ and a positive maximum in the interval $(1/2,1)$. Finally, we can observe that $\lim_{t\to0}f(t)=\lim_{t\to1}f(t)=0$, so the final conclusion is that $f$ only vanishes at $1/2$.

So the unique solution is $a=b=2$.

---

You *might* want to “extend” this to negative values of $a$, but the only ways I see is to either declare that you want to find $a<0$ such that $a+b$, $ab$ and $-|a|^b$ have the same value. Your idea of approximating with unit fractions can only work if you already *know* the value you want to approach. Anyway, for the *changed* problem, we can see that $b>0$ so the problem transforms into finding $b,c>0$ such that $b<c$ and $b-c$, $bc$ and $c^b$ have the same value.

Now you see that $b-c=bc$ implies $b=c/(1-c)$, so $c<1$. Then
$$
b-1=\frac{2c-1}{c}
$$
and you can proceed similarly as before.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122820/discussion-on-answer-by-egreg-when-two-values-a-and-b-have-the-same-value).

Comment: Can you delete this answer while you're at it?